# Printf command after an if statement does not work

Tags: c

I just started programming a couple of days ago. I tried to program something that calculates my CGPA. I haven't completed it yet; for example, I have to improve the menu etc. It works properly for the 1st and 3rd choice. I will do something else for the second choice. The problem is, after calculation, it doesn't print the text "qwerty" on the bottom.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char h[2];
    double numGrade;
    double credit, percent, overallCredit, sumCredit;
    double contribution=0, GPA=0, semGPA=0, CGPA=0;
    int courseNum, i, semesters, k, menu;


    printf("Input\n\"1\" for computing your CGPA\n\"2\" if you know each semester's GPA\n\"3\" if you know your CGPA\n");
    scanf("%d", &menu);

    if(menu == 1)
    {
        printf("Enter the number of semesters you have studied: ");
        scanf("%d", &semesters);

        for(k=1; k<=semesters; k++)
        {
            printf("Enter the number of courses you took in semester %d: ", k);
            scanf("%d", &courseNum);
            overallCredit = 0;
            sumCredit = 0;

            for(i=1; i<=courseNum; i++)
            {
                printf("Enter the credit of the course %d: ", i);
                scanf("%lf", &credit);
                overallCredit += credit;
                printf("Enter your letter grade: ");
                scanf("%s", h);


                if(strcmp(h, "AA") == 0)
                {
                    numGrade = 4.0;
                }else if(strcmp(h, "BA") == 0)
                {
                    numGrade = 3.5;
                }else if(strcmp(h, "BB") == 0)
                {
                    numGrade = 3.0;
                }else if(strcmp(h, "CB") == 0)
                {
                    numGrade = 2.5;
                }else if(strcmp(h, "CC") == 0)
                {
                    numGrade = 2.0;
                }else if(strcmp(h, "DC") == 0)
                {
                    numGrade = 1.5;
                }else if(strcmp(h, "DD") == 0)
                {
                    numGrade = 1.0;
                }else if(strcmp(h, "FD") == 0)
                {
                    numGrade = 0.5;
                }else if(strcmp(h, "DD") == 0)
                {
                    numGrade = 0.0;
                }else
                {
                    printf("Invalid Grade\n");
                }

                percent = numGrade/4.0;
                contribution = percent*credit;
                sumCredit += contribution;

            }GPA = (sumCredit/overallCredit)*4.0;
            printf("Your GPA for semester %d is: %f\n", k, GPA);
            semGPA += GPA;

        }CGPA = semGPA/semesters;
        printf("CGPA is: %.2f", CGPA+0.005);
    }else
    {
        printf("Enter your CGPA: ");
        scanf("%lf", &CGPA);
        printf("Your CGPA is: %.2f", CGPA+0.005);

    }       
    printf("qwerty"); //This does not print.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", h);` missing `&`? Also what input did you give?

Comment: @SMA  `h` is a char string (albeit very short)

Comment: Does print for me.

Comment: By the way I am trying to compute another exam after my CGPA and combine them to get an overall score. That's why I want to be able to write after the if statement.

Comment: "scanf("%s", h); missing &?" Do you need '&' for strings?

Comment: @CandasErsoz No, you don't need the `&` for string arguments to `scanf` (an array decays to a pointer in such circumstances). Problem solved, though (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're running into ***undefined behaviour***! (This means anything can happen - code will work, sometimes, not work, sometimes, and maybe even wipe your hard disk, sometimes.)

This happens because you are trying to read too many characters into your `h` variable: you have declared it: `char h[2]`, which can hold *only one* letter plus the terminating `nul`. But you try to read *two* letters into it. Declare it a bit longer: `char h[3]` and your code should work. But it's maybe better to be safer, and declare it longer, say `char h[20];`, in case the user types too much data in; alternatively, specify in the input format a maximum string length: `scanf("%2s", h);`, which will truncate (ignore) any letters after the second.

In your code, the `scanf` operation writes beyond the memory allocated to `h` and, thus, maybe changes other 'control' variables in the compiled code.

*EDIT: PS, it may not actually be the `scanf` call that triggers the undefined behaviour! It could be the subsequent `strcmp` call - the `h` argument to this will not have a `nul` terminator and the function will then overflow the string buffer, looking for a zero.*

Comment: Thank you for the warning, I did as you said and declarded h longer but it still does not print. I think the reason it does not print is the menu I created keeps if statement positive and it never gets to "if not" statement where my print function is defined. So whatever code I write it will not print unless I take the if statement in a for loop and keep printf outside so when the if statement is complete it will go out of the for loop and run print function. Right?

Comment: @CandasErsoz That's not the problem! You have one large `if` block and a subsequent `else`; one of these will run (the former if `menu == 1)` but only run **once**. Then the `printf` that is after *both* blocks will run. It does on my system.

Comment: @CandasErsoz Does this line: `printf("CGPA is: %.2f", CGPA + 0.005);` run?

Comment: @CandasErsoz Also, note that you will not printf "qwerty" on a separate line! It appears on the same line as the previous output: `"CGPA is : 4.00qwerty"`.

Comment: Yes that line works I just made it to round numbers up, for example 3.175 is supposed to round up to 3.18 but it does not so I just ad 0.005 it rounds up and I take the first 2 decimal numbers. However, when it is 3.174 it rounds down to 3.17 even if you add 0.005 because the sum is 3.179

Comment: I do not see "qwerty" at all. It doesn't print, also I tried scanf too. It does not work as well.